# XSL to convert UTC time to local datetime with an offset compare

Tags: java, datetime, xslt, xslt-1.0, utc

We receive datetime elements relative to the UTC time like `2004-04-12T13:20:00Z`.

And we would like to output the datetime in the local datetime, that is expressed with an offset relative to the UTC time like `2004-04-12T12:20:00-01:00`.

Can someone help to achieve this in XSLT?
Or does exist a function-template to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert a given dateTime value to the **current** local timezone, use the `adjust-dateTime-to-timezone()` function, without specifying the `timezone` parameter.

For example:

```
<xsl:variable name="datetime">2004-04-12T13:20:00Z</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone($datetime)"/>
```

will return:

```
2004-04-12T12:20:00-01:00
```

if, at the time of the transformation, your system's local time is offset -1 hour from UTC.

---

### Important:

This may not produce the expected results if your local time's offset from UTC is not constant, but changes due to daylight-saving time. To convert correctly a date from April 2004 to what the local time was back then, you would need to know what your offset from UTC was at that specific point in time. XSLT does not have this capability, and you would have to do the conversion in another application that can access the [Olson database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

---

### Added:

All of the above requires XSLT 2.0. Since you have now clarified you are actually using XSLT 1.0:

1. XSLT 1.0 has no way of knowing what the current local offset from UTC is - let alone what the offset was at the given point in time.
2. There is a way to adjust the given dateTime value to another
   timezone - provided you supply the required offset as a parameter
   when calling the XSL transformation (or that the offset is
   constant).

Here's an example of a template that will convert UTC to UTC -1:00 (as constant):

```
<xsl:template name="UTC-minus-one">
    <xsl:param name="dateTime"/>

    <xsl:variable name="date" select="substring-before($dateTime, 'T')" />
    <xsl:variable name="time" select="substring-before(substring-after($dateTime, 'T'), 'Z')" />

    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($date, 1, 4)" />
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring($date, 6, 2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($date, 9, 2)" />

    <xsl:variable name="hour" select="substring($time, 1, 2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="minute" select="substring($time, 4, 2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="second" select="substring($time, 7)" />

    <xsl:variable name="a" select="floor((14 - $month) div 12)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="$year + 4800 - $a"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="$month + 12*$a - 3"/>    
    <xsl:variable name="jd" select="$day + floor((153*$m + 2) div 5) + 365*$y + floor($y div 4) - floor($y div 100) + floor($y div 400) - 32045" />

    <xsl:variable name="total-seconds" select="86400*$jd + 3600*$hour + 60*$minute + $second - 3600" />

    <xsl:variable name="new-jd" select="floor($total-seconds div 86400)"/>  
    <xsl:variable name="new-hour" select="floor($total-seconds mod 86400 div 3600)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="new-minute" select="floor($total-seconds mod 3600 div 60)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="new-second" select="$total-seconds mod 60"/>

    <xsl:variable name="f" select="$new-jd + 1401 + floor((floor((4 * $new-jd + 274277) div 146097) * 3) div 4) - 38"/>
    <xsl:variable name="e" select="4*$f + 3"/>
    <xsl:variable name="g" select="floor(($e mod 1461) div 4)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="h" select="5*$g + 2"/>
    <xsl:variable name="D" select="floor(($h mod 153) div 5 ) + 1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="M" select="(floor($h div 153) + 2) mod 12 + 1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Y" select="floor($e div 1461) - 4716 + floor((14 - $M) div 12)"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="concat($Y, format-number($M, '-00'), format-number($D, '-00'))"/>
    <xsl:text>T</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number($new-hour, '00'), format-number($new-minute, ':00'), format-number($new-second, ':00.###'))"/>
    <xsl:text>-01:00</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

**Demo**: http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5F8

Comment: Can you please provide the code on how to transform this using xslt1.0?

Comment: @VJoe How to transform this to what?

Comment: How to transform 2004-04-12T13:20:00Z to 2004-04-12T12:20:00-01:00. We know for sure that our offset value is -1. How to make it happen using xslt1.0

Comment: @michael.hor257k, where is the -1 parameter set? I need +1 :-) EDIT: Foundt it with -3600 sec

Answer (score 2):

Assuming an XML test file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <val>2004-04-12T13:20:00Z</val>
    <val>2004-05-12T23:20:00Z</val>
    <val>2004-06-12T00:20:00Z</val>
</root>
```

An XSLT-2.0 file like this will set the timezone to `-1`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="//val">
  <xsl:variable name="t_offset" select="xs:dayTimeDuration('-PT1H')" />     <!-- set timezone to -1 hours -->
  <xsl:variable name="time"     select="xs:dateTime(normalize-space(text()))"  />
  <xsl:value-of select="$time" />
  <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'" />
  <xsl:value-of select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone($time, $t_offset)" />   <!-- adjust the time to the new timezone -->
  <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'" />
  <xsl:value-of select="'------------------&#10;'" />
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is:

```
2004-04-12T13:20:00Z
2004-04-12T12:20:00-01:00
------------------
2004-05-12T23:20:00Z
2004-05-12T22:20:00-01:00
------------------
2004-06-12T00:20:00Z
2004-06-11T23:20:00-01:00
------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But we are using xslt1.0 processor and this seems to be used for xslt2.0 processors. Can you please suggest and answer for xslt1.0 as well?

Comment: @VJoe Why is your question tagged as `xslt-2.0` then?

Comment: my bad. Corrected it to 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Oracle SOA suite for transformation.

```
xp20:subtract-dayTimeDuration-from-dateTime (/ns0:Your/@DateTime, concat (&quot;PT&quot;, substring-after (substring-before (xp20:timezone-from-dateTime (xp20:current-dateTime() ), &quot;:&quot; ), &quot;-0&quot; ), &quot;H&quot; ) )
```

This should solve your issue